# How to Remove 1940s Stem Mount Light Fixture

Tags: lighting

I’m trying to replace this light fixture in my rental home in San Francisco. I removed the old chandelier but there is a fixed “stem” protruding from the ceiling and it will not budge. Any ideas for how to remove? I can’t replace the fixture without removing the stem.

Any and all suggestions accepted[image]

Comment: That appears to be a "Luminaire stud" with some other bits attached to it. As already answered, it should unscrew; in a rental, in an area ruled by NEC, you should not be doing this work, though.

Answer (score 2):

The stem should unscrew when rotated counterclockwise (as viewed looking into its end). If you really can't persuade it to come lose, you may want to consider replacing the entire electrical box.

Reminder: In a rental unit, YOU MUST GET THE OWNER'S PERMISSION BEFORE MAKING ANY ELECTRICAL CHANGES. AND THOSE MAY NEED TO BE PERFORMED BY A LICENSED ELECTRICIAN.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks, I do have permission. We will try to unscrew again. Thanks!